# CKFinder issue cannot get event when an image has been uploaded

Tags: javascript, ckfinder

I am using CKFinder 3 in a single page Application, I need to detect when an image upload has been successful.

At the moment I am using `createResources:after` with no success.

Any idea how to solve this, I meanly need to solve this in the JS code ?

```
            onInit: function( finder ) {
                finder.on('createResources:after', function (event) {
                    // issue here, does not fire
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently the CKFinder API up to version 3.3 doesn't have any events for uploads. There are plans to add those events in 3.4.

The [createResources:after](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3/#!/api/CKFinder.Application-event-createResources_after) event is fired when a [Resource Type](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-php/configuration.html#configuration_options_resourceTypes) is created. A resource type is simply a group of files under a root path.

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, I am evaluating demo of ckFinder for our project, I have question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269039/ckfinder-how-to-get-dimension-url-and-dimension-width-height-when-choosing-an     I would really appreciate your feedback :) many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: @GibboK OK, no problem.

Comment: Hi, we are still in the evaluation phase of ckFinder, we still have an issue related with EDIT feature, I really would appreciate your feedback and expertise on this. Please look here if you have time. Thanks in advance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35288396/ckfinder-edit-features-does-not-work-when-working-on-different-domain