# CKFinder how to get dimension URL and Dimension (width/height) when choosing an image (files:choose)?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckfinder

I am using CkFinder 3, after uploading successfully an image I need to be able to detect after an User click the "Chose" button:

- file name / id
- url
- width and height for original image

At the moment I am using the `files:choose` but I cannot find this information on the cb event.

Any idea how to solve it? A sample of code would be appreciate thanks.

```
    CKFinder.modal( {
        connectorPath: 'https://api.mysite.com/lib/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php',
        resizeImages: false, 
        startupFolderExpanded: true,
        chooseFiles: true,
        width: 1000,
        height: 800,
        language: 'en',
        onInit: function( finder ) {
            finder.on( 'files:choose', function( evt ) {
            } );
        }
    } );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taking example from the [`files:choose`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3/#!/api/CKFinder.Application-event-files_choose) event description. You get [`Backbone.Collection`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection) of [files](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3/#!/api/CKFinder.Models.File) chosen by the user in `evt.data.files`.

The tricky part is to obtain image dimensions from [`ImageInfo`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-php/commands.html#command_image_info) server (using the [`command:send`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3/#!/api/CKFinder.Application-request-command_send) request) since it requires to process asynchronous code with promises.

Assuming that you only allow Images to be uploaded, example code is below:

```
// Listen to event.
finder.on( 'files:choose', function( evt ) {
    // Iterate over the files collection.
    evt.data.files.forEach( function( file ) {
        // Send command to the server.
        finder.request( 'command:send', {
            name: 'ImageInfo',
            folder: file.get( 'folder' ),
            params: { fileName: file.get( 'name' ) }
        } ).done( function( response ) {
            // Process server response.
            if ( response.error ) {
                // Some error handling.
                return;
            }

            // Log image data:
            console.log( '-------------------' );
            console.log( 'Name:', file.get( 'name' ) );
            console.log( 'URL:', file.getUrl() );
            console.log( 'Dimensions:', response.width + 'x' + response.height );
            console.log( 'Size:', response.size + 'B' );
        } );
    } );
} )
```

If you are using any remote backend such us Dropbox you might need to use the [`file:getUrl`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3/#!/api/CKFinder.Application-request-file_getUrl) request to obtain the file's URL.