# CKFinder "Edit" features does not work when working on different domains

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor, ckfinder, camanjs

We are evaluating CKFinder, at the moment we have this situation:

- **app**.domain.com  hosts our JS application included ckfinder.js
- **api**.domain.com  hosts the connector.php

Please note they are on different domains.

We are able to view files and folders with no problems.

The issue is related the `EDIT feature`. When user select an Image and click "Edit" Button, CKFinder goes in editing mode but with receive an error and the image cannot be edited:

```
response (status cancelled)
URL:about:/blank?camanProxyUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.domain.com%2Flib%2Fckfinder%2Fcore%2Fconnector%2Fphp%2Fconnector.php%3Fcommand%3DThumbnail%26lang%3Den%26type%3DImages%26currentFolder%3D%252F%26hash%3D7c47bbd7d0c05357%26fileName%3Dfile-aaa-Image-Sample-6.jpg%26date%3D20160208110210%26fileSize%3D206
```

It looks like an issue with some php proxy CKFinder is using.

Maybe related to this component: https://github.com/ckfinder/CamanJS/tree/master/docs

We would need to r**un the EDIT feature but keeping the same domain organization** as we have.

Any solution is very welcome thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, cross-domain setups are not supported in CKFinder at the moment. As it is, `ckfinder.js` and `connector.php` should be located in the same domain. Do note it's not just a matter of hacking the Edit feature, other areas of the application including some security-related ones will not work either.

Comment: Are you planning some support in the future?

Comment: Not at the moment - this is a bit of an unusual setup, we haven't had any requests for this from our customers so far. And like I said, it could potentially make some security-related features not work or require a significant effort to extend them to support this. And security is a priority issue in an application that is deployed to your server and allows people to upload stuff there...

Comment: Hi maybe you can give us a feedback in solving this configuration, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35294334/ckfinder-edit-mode-how-to-set-save-changes-preferences-overwrite-file  I would really appreciate your expertise on this. Thanks in advance for your time.