# CkFinder "Edit" mode how to set Save Changes preferences (Overwrite File)

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor, ckfinder

We are evaluating CkFinder 3.2.0, we have an issue with setting some configurations/preferences.

After uploading an image, user can select it and making some modification using "Edit" feature.

At the moment of saving the modified image, a dialog appears giving the option to  **Overwrite File** or not, if user select NO, a "Save As" text box appear.

We need to:

- Disable Overwrite File option at all.
- When an "Edit" on an image happens we want just to create a new file (no overwrite option), with a version number at the end of the file name.

or

- Always shows the""Save As" text box, so an User is forced to enter a different name for the modified image.

Do CkFinder offer this feature? If yes, how to use it?

Comment: All of the CKEditor options are located [here](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html).  Have you looked to see if your option is there?  If what you're looking for isn't there, have you tried asking CKFinder?  See also [here](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Setting_Configurations).

Comment: I suppose is a server side configuration, but I cannot find reference here:http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-php/configuration.html I will double check your link, thanks for sharing!

Comment: @RobertHarvey link provided looks like only for CKEDITOR, I need some configuration for ckFinder instead. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry. The CKFinder configuration page is [here](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder_2.x_api/symbols/CKFinder.config.html).

Comment: @RobertHarvey it is for version 2, I am using 3.2.0 :)

Comment: Well, the complete documentation for CKFinder 3 is [here](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3/#!/guide).  See, this is why we're always asking people for their prior research.  If you need custom functionality, it would seem that [writing a plugin](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3/#!/guide/dev_plugins) is the way to go.